# Facing issue while running test cases in xcode10

Tags: objective-c, xctest, xcode10, ios-frameworks

I am facing **xctest encountered error** while executing test cases in xcode 10.

The error says

> Showing All Messages
>   xctest (5571) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, the operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. Underlying error: Test session exited(82) without checking in. The executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements mismatch. Retry after a Clean build.)

The same code works fine in Xcode **9.4.1** or below. 
Tried all possible solutions over the internet but the issue still exists. The project is in objective C and its a **framework** project.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Attached the screenshot of the error

[image]

Comment: Did you already tried all the Voodoo? (delete Derived-Date, remove build folder, restart Xcode, restart Mac, reinstall Xcode 10)